# Ubuntu 14.04 ignoring SLAAC IPv6 configuration

Tags: ipv6, ubuntu-14.04

I am having issues getting an Ubuntu 14.04 server to pickup an IPv6 address through SLAAC. I have gone through the process of changing all the configuration settings I could find through google, but it's still stuck with the fe80:: Scope:Link address.

My interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

I've added the following line to my sysctl.conf file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr=0
```

And when I check the other sysctl settings I get the following:

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.force_tllao = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mldv1_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mldv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mtu = 1500
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.ndisc_notify = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.regen_max_retry = 3
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.router_solicitations = 3
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.suppress_frag_ndisc = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 0
```

I'm looking for any other places that I need to change settings, or if there is a log I should be looking at to diagnose why I'm still getting the fe80:: address instead of a SLAAC based address.

Other computers on the same network windows, linux, mac all get IPv6 addresses normally.

Comment: Post the output of `ip addr` and also check `dmesg`.

Comment: You know you don't lose the fe80:: link-local address once you get a globally-routable address right?

Comment: What makes you think you would lose an fe80 address?

Comment: Could you also show the values for net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding and net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding? Did you check for router solicitations/advertisements with Wireshark or similar?

Comment: Would you be able to test with any other Ubuntu 14.04 machines? I am wondering if what you have found is a difference between the server and desktop editions. It might also be that it is just a misconfiguration on that specific host. SLAAC has certainly been working for me with Ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition in the default configuration.

Comment: Make sure that you are actually getting Router Advertisements from your router and that they have the M, O and A bits set as you expect.

Comment: One more thing - if you have a DCHPv6 client running, then no SLAAC (in most but not all cases).